# How to get local network IP address of a remote computer

Tags: c, network-programming, ip

A remote computer has two address: **LAN** and **VPN**

I tried to get **LAN** IP address by following code:

```
hostent *host = gethostbyname(hostname);
if (host) strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr)));
```

So, sometime it return **LAN**, but sometime **VPN**. I know that there're many address in h_addr_list field, but how can I know which address is local?

I tried to use GetAdaptersInfo(), it has field to determine local ip or not, but just return ip address of my computer. I don't know how to get ip for remote computer.

Anyone give me some advices, please!

Comment: Your local host most likely cannot distinguish them anyway, but you could try to match the list of ips from the remote with your local network mask of the respective connection (e.g. eth0).

Comment: Thanks! I thought about that, but it just be a guess. So reserve it as a backup plan. I want to absolutely get that ip through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this problem, I realize that the adapters on remote string could not be public due to security issue. Thus, we don't have an exactly way to know which IP address is VPN.

Moreover, VPN address is created by VPN server. Therefore, that VPN address could be anything, even similar to our local IP. In other words, we cannot guess VPN address any way.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question you state that you can get the lan IP of your computer and get the ip's of the remote computer be it both LAN or VPN. To determine which IP on the remote computer is on your lan you can use a subnet test, I assume that your VPN is on a different subnet of course, and you can essentially test if the first 2-3 octets of your computer's ip matches that of the 2-3 octets of the remote ip. This is the only way I can think of to do it.

So, loop through the remote IP's as you say you can get them and check them against the local ip address of your computer's octets.

Comment: I think that's one possible solution, but OP didn't seem to like it when I suggested it the comments.

Comment: Totally did not see your comment. It's the only one that I can think of really that would not require any more work than this problem already requires.

Comment: So is it the only solution for now? I will implement that way until having a better one. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just can't think of another way without an external service to be honest.

Comment: I implemented yesterday, after putting to test, I realize that VPN IP could be similar with LAN IP (LAN-172.16.0.47 vs VPN-172.16.0.97 on test machine)

Comment: Ah, well that is a problem. I cannot think of anything else on how to figure out which is which without the remote computer telling you then.  `Ask for local ip -> Client figures it out -> sends back local ip.`